# SQL select by date from today

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, mariadb

I'm studying SQL (Using MariaDB 10.2) and I'm using a huge example database I found online. It has an 'employees' table, and this one has a 'birth_date' column of 'date' type. I want to select all those employees who are more than 50 years old, for example, or maybe those who will be 25 years old on an specific date . Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add or subtract `interval`s to `date`s:

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee
WHERE  birth_date <= NOW() - INTERVAL 50 YEAR
```

Comment: This is the best approach.  It is accurate to the day and the query can use an index.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming t-sql, then for those over 50 today, use:

```
select * from employees where datediff(year, birth_date, now()) > 50
```

For those who will be 25 on a certain date use:

```
select * from employees where datediff(year, birthdate, certain_date) = 25
```

Comment: For me this results in an error `DATEDIFF` only has 2 params in mysql/mariadb: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/datediff/. i guess your query runs well in T-SQL :)

Comment: Yes; I'm so sorry, I didn't specify which SQL.  I meant for t-sql for ms sqlserver.  For mysql you would not use the first parameter ("year") and you would always get your answer in days, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE(myDate) = DATE(NOW())
```

This is for MySql DB

Comment: Wouldn't this select all employees born today (with an age of 0)?

Comment: Ok @Roland I will try.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use INTERVAL function which you can add or subtract Dates:**

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE birth_date <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 50 YEAR);
```

- NOW() -----> Present Date
- -INTERVAL 50 YEAR -----> Subtract that Date to 50 Years